# Camera creates new folder after every 999 images. How can I change that?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3300

I have a Nikon D3300 and ample amount of space on its memory card. However I have noticed a pattern that it creates a new folder after reaching 1000 images in one folder.

For instance, DSC_001 to DSC_099 in one folder and then the following images in a seperate folder. How can I make it save everything I shoot in the same folder? I have looked all the settings on the camera and still cannot figure it out.

The problem it creates is that when I copy the photos to my laptop, the previous set of 999 images have the same name as the new set of photos that I take. For this reason I have been unable to save all the related images from one day/trip/event in the same folder on my computer.

UPDATE: 
1. I pop the SD card from the camera and use inbuilt card reader on my laptop to transfer images.
2. In the new folder that the camera creates, the images start from DSC_000 to DSC_999 making it impossible for me to save all images in 1 folder on my laptop.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to download/copy the images to your laptop? Are you using specialized software or the built in operation system tools? Please describe.

Comment: Is it the folder name or the resetting to 0001 that is the problem?

Comment: Your statement is wrong. It is totally possible to store the images in one folder - just rename them with a prefix. You want to rename them anyway so you can key in date, a shot reference and a load / camera ID, otherwise you start falling apart sooner or later anyway.

Comment: I took the suggestion of user 'ths' and turned the file number sequencing ON so that even if the camera creates new folder, all images will be named in continuous increasing number. I should be able to copy them in a single folder on my laptop without overwriting. That's the best and easy workaround I have found thus far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your cameras [reference manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Wywwt00lh46s0109T7E089fAaV06/D3300RM_(En)02.pdf), page 249, the menu setting "file number sequence" is described:

> - On
>
> When a new folder is created, the memory card
> formatted, or a new memory card inserted in the camera, file numbering
> continues from the last number used. If a photograph is taken when the
> current folder contains a photograph numbered 9999, a new folder will
> be created automatically and file numbering will begin again from
> 0001.
>
> - Off
>
> File numbering is reset to 0001 when a new folder is created, the memory card is
> formatted, or a new memory card is inserted in the camera. Note that a
> new folder is created automatically if a photograph is taken when the
> current folder contains 999 photographs

So, if you set this to "On", your photos will be numbered continuously up to 9999, spanning folders.
(Unfortunately, only 4 significant digits are available)

There is no setting to put all photos in one folder (probably because of performance problems on FAT file systems), but this will help solve your problem of duplicate file names.

Comment: Thank you. I found that setting and have turned it ON. Even if the new folder issue cannot be solved, at least I should now be able to copy all images without fear of overwriting old images.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix for anyone with basic computing skills is to rename the files after the transfer. Here is a simple Bash script which renames files using the folder as a prefix.

```
#!/bin/sh

for d; do
    for f in "$d"/*; do
        mv "$f" "$d"_"${f#$d}"
    done
done
```

So for example, given DSC_001 and DSC_002, if you saved this script as `photorenamer`, you would run it like

```
sh ./photorenamer DSC_001 DSC_002
```

and it would rename `DSC_001/image00001.jpg` to `DSC_001_image00001.jpg`, and `DSC_002/image00001.jpg to DSC_002_image00001.jpg`, etc etc.

Traditional Windows CMD is much more horrible to write a simple script for, but Powershell should be roughly on par with what you can do in a Linux shell, albeit rather more verbose. (Maybe also notice the differences between different Unix shells; this is simple enough that it should work on any Linux or Unix-like system, but understand that it might require tweaks if you try to run it on the command line in a shell which isn't POSIX-compatible.)

Comment: I use a very old version of XXCOPY in DOS box to add folder number and date to end of file name. A: is pointed to source. Current directory is target. Works superbly. || xxcopy /bu /sx /m /nx0 %1:\dcim\*.j* a:\  || /sx achieves the suffix addition.

Comment: Please feel fee to update the answer with a bog standard PowerShell variant. I don't think more esoteric third-party tools for Windows victims are worthy of more than a comment.

Comment: I wrote a brief section about how you could save this script in your `PATH` and call it without `sh` but it got too long so I took it out; it's better if you google that separately. In brief, create `$HOME/bin` and add it to your `PATH`; `chmod +x` the scripts you put there.

Comment: XXCOPT technical reference [here](http://fekete.x10host.com/xxtb3000.htm) Hundreds of switches - very nicely grouped and nested. A joy to use :-). One could do worse than addingh this "DOS" tool to on' stable.

Comment: Some Windows victims live some of their lives in the dark blackness of the DOS box, remembering days of yore, & DOS 2 .... .  (I had DOS1 on a diskette but never run). My version of XXCOPY  is from early 2001 - it's done its task well for me this 20+ years.  I stuck with that version because why not, and later versions did not allow free use. Now ALL versions are public domain. || Products shown as freeware [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171127204432/http://pixelab.com/) - the site has now vanished and links are dead but feeware status was shown from mid 2017 until site died.